# I broke apt while trying to upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, 19.04

**O.S:** Ubuntu 19.04 (disco)

Running `sudo do-release-upgrade` i got the following message:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release Your Ubuntu release is not supported
> anymore. For upgrade information, please visit:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
>
> Please install all available updates for your release before
> upgrading.

Doing an `apt upgrade` i got this one:

> The following packages have been kept back:
> libsnmp30

That package couldn't be updated because it required `libsensors5` but existing packages were using `libsensors4`.
So i ran multiple commands from internet that manually installed `libsensors5` and removed `libsensors4`.

Now i'm stuck on this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
libgl1-mesa-dri :
Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable  
libsnmp30 : 
Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable 
E: Unmet dependencies. 
Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried doing `apt install libsensors4` but it doesn't let me as now i have v5.

How can i fix this mess so i can finally upgrade?

Comment: You didnt say, but do you tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Yes, response is the same :( The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: Removing mesa drives won't break my laptop? that thread tells me to remove libgl1-mesa-dri & libsnmp30

Comment: I won't be playing with removing that package (even if it's already broken.. I think you can try to reinstall it, if it is in your repositories (`apt search libgl1-mesa-dri`)). This package isn't uptodate (since mine in 20.04 depends on libsensors5 > 1.3.5 ).

Comment: Yes it is, but installing says: libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version :(

Comment: you have to use the `--reinstall` flag just before the package name

Comment: (you didnt add the results of `apt install libsensors4` in your first post)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [The Debian Way](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-04-lts-focal-fossa#h4-how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-the-debian-way) to upgrade your system. You have an issue because you are on `disco` (non-LTS) but `disco` is no more since `eoan`. And this is because `disco` is no more you can't install it with the apt/source.list .

I recommend you to make a backup if something goes wrong. Because you never know, when upgrading your system.

---

## The Debian Way

In your case, you use neither of `bionic` or `eoan`, so you have to edit the commands that the a

```
sudo sed -i 's/disco/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
```

> When the Ubuntu upgrade does finish, reboot the system. When the
> system comes back up, you'll be running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa!

---

sources : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-04-lts-focal-fossa#h4-how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-the-debian-way

---

## Edit :

When I try *some things on the internet*, I do everything in the terminal because I add `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` in my `$HOME/.bashrc` file, and I make backup of every files I edit (`cp file.cfg file.cfg.bk`).

**What does it do ?** Every command I run in the terminal instantly happend in the `$HOME/.bash_history` file. Therefore, if I do something wrong, I can find my way back.

**Ideally**, you would make a write-up for that in a `file.md`, with URL, etc. First, because if you have to do it again. Second, because if something goes wrong. Third, because it might be helpful for someone, on day, right here in askubuntu.com ;-)

Comment: apt update explodes with that change: Ign:13 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease Err:14 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80] Err:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80] Get:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages [12.5 kB] Err:17 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release 404  Not Found , etc..

Comment: You can revert back anytime with `sudo sed -i 's/focal/disco/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`. I'm looking later for what's wrong. In the meantime, please report the previous return in your main post, clikcing on "Edit". Also, try to find the /etc/apt/source.list of the classic Ubuntu 20.04 version, backup yours and use them instead.

Comment: Try `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bk1 && sudo curl https://termbin.com/vscr > /etc/apt/sources.list` ; that's my `sources.list` file. Try it and try to `sudo apt update` (dont do anything else in case of errors).
To reverse, simply do `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.bk1 /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: The Debian way is neither recommended nor a tested method to upgrade a Ubuntu release. Upgrading that way may cause many obsolete packages residing in the system. Also, since default Python version in Ubuntu varies from release to release, it may happen that you'll get completely broken python since if you observe closely, while upgrading using Ubuntu's upgrade tool, DPKG holds some packages to avoid dependency issues. Related: [Is editing sources.list a good idea?](/questions/1061450)